# Android Jelly Bean animations strange behavior

Tags: android, animation, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am developing an app for versions of Android that go from ICS and up (4.0+). In my app I am using animations that animate properties on target objects (using ObjectAnimator) and here is a code snippet:

```
    Animator disappearingAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(regularScreenLayout, "alpha", 1f, 0f);

    AnimatorSet appearingAnimations = new AnimatorSet();
    Animator appearingAnimationAlpha = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(statisticsScreenLayout, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
    Animator appearingAnimationTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(statistics_wrapper, "y",
            changingContent.getHeight(), 0);
    appearingAnimations.playTogether(appearingAnimationTranslate, appearingAnimationAlpha);

    AnimatorSet animations = new AnimatorSet();
    animations.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME);
    animations.playTogether(disappearingAnimation, appearingAnimations);
    animations.start();
```

All of my animations are working perfectly on all versions of ICS, but on devices that have Jelly Bean they start behaving strange. For example, if I want to change the visibility of some view with an disappearing animation, the view only appears/disappears without the animation (animations don't work!). Have someone had this kind of problem, or knows what could be the cause and how to solve it, I would appreciate it. Share your experience. Thx

Answer (score 0):

As much as it sounds strange, I solved this problem by making a combination with view and properties animations (as you can see in my code snippet I was using only properties animations). So, the animations that were more simple, I did them using view animations (defined in xml), and the ones that required properties changes, i did them with the new properties animations. This solved the problem for me, and now everything is working properly on both ICS and Jelly Bean devices. Hope this helps!